# How can I set the function to a state without the function being called?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set a function to a state. The problem I'm having, is that when I set the state the function gets called. How can I set the function to a state without the function being called?

```
const [submitCallbackFunction, setSubmitCallbackFunction] = useState();
```

Child Component

```
props.setSubmitCallbackFunction(scrollToSection); // Don't call scrollToSection when setting setSubmitCallbackFunction

function scrollToDonationSection() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Can you provide more code? Such as the rest of your component including the render statement? Also, whether or not your `scrollToSection` function is called depends on what `setSubmitCallbackFunction`does. Are you passing a setter from `useState` as a prop or does that function come from elsewhere?

Comment: @Khauri setSubmitCallbackFunctiondoes  is created like this: const [submitCallbackFunction, setSubmitCallbackFunction] = useState();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example of how to do this although, I don't know if it should be solved this way:

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-solomon-m91sv)

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

import "./styles.css";

const function1 = () => console.log("Func 1!");
const function2 = () => console.log("Func 2!");

const ChildComponent = ({ setSubmitCallbackFunction }) => {
  return (
    <button onClick={() => setSubmitCallbackFunction(() => function2)}>
      Update!
    </button>
  );
};

const App = () => {
  const [submitCallbackFunction, setSubmitCallbackFunction] = useState(
    () => function1
  );

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={submitCallbackFunction}>Test submit func</button>
      <ChildComponent setSubmitCallbackFunction={setSubmitCallbackFunction} />
    </div>
  );
};

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Comment: Not necessarily bad @Jessica, I just don't know as much about the use case and if there is a way to do this without putting functions in state. One possible solution is to set a variable in state and conditionally change the function you use instead of putting the function itself in state.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to take a guess at your problem here.

There are two ways to use the [`useState` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html), one is to pass it a value, and the other is to pass it a function whose first argument will be the previous value of the state variable like so:

```js
const [state, setState] = useState(0)
// somewhere else in the code
setState((prev) => prev + 1)
```

Because you're passing a function to `useState`, the hook is assuming that you're trying to do it the second way. AKA [lazy initialization](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#lazy-initial-state)

A simple way around this would be to just call `setState` with a function that returns a function like so:

```js
setState(()=>myFunction)
```

Something to keep in mind is that you shouldn't call your setState function within the main body of your component. In this case, this will cause the parent to re-render, which will re-render the child, which will call the setter again, which will cause the parent to re-render, and so on. Instead you might want to use `useEffect` to have it run only once.

```js
useEffect(()=>{
  setSubmitCallbackFunction(()=>scrollToSection)
}, [ ])
```